# Why does my instance not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, class, methods, constructor

I've used an if statement to determine which constructor an instance should use, however it claims that it doesn't exist in the current context. I've used the method `GetDetails` which should get the full name, along with the eye colour and age, however both are optional. It should then determine which constructor it should use, depending on the user input.

After that, it will call the function `IntroduceMyself`, which simply introduces themselves. This function is in the other class called `Human`, which contains all the constructors. The code isn't entirely finished and still has errors, however I want to understand what this error is and how to fix it.

This is the main class:

```
class Program
{
    static string fullName;
    static string eyeColour;
    static int age;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetDetails();
        
        if (eyeColour == "")
        { 
            Human person1 = new Human(fullName); 
        }
        else if (eyeColour != "")
        { 
            Human person1 = new Human(fullName, eyeColour); 
        }
        else
        { 
            Human person1 = new Human(fullName, eyeColour, age); 
        }

        person1.IntroduceMyself(fullName, eyeColour, age);
    }

    public static void GetDetails()
    {    
        Console.Write("Hello! To start, please enter your full name:");
        fullName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Would you like to input your eye colour? y / n :");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your eye colour:");
            eyeColour = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.Write("Would you like to input your age? y / n :");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your age:");
            while(!(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)))
            {
                Console.Write("There was an error! Please try again:");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the human class:

```
internal class Human
{
    public string fullName;
    public string eyeColour;
    public int age;

    public Human(string fullName)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Human(string fullName, string eyeColour)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.eyeColour = eyeColour;
    }

    public Human(string fullName, string eyeColour, int age)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.eyeColour = eyeColour;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void IntroduceMyself(string fullName, string eyeColour, int age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, you have {1} eyes and you are {2} years old", fullName, eyeColour, age);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is static.  Static objects you do not reference in an instance.  Instead you directly access using the class name : Human.IntroduceMyself()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want to understand what this error is" - what error, precisely? You haven't told us what's wrong. Also, it really doesn't help if you're presenting code with *multiple* errors, but you're only interested in one of them. It would be much better if you'd present a code example which *just* demonstrates the error you want help with.

Comment: The `Human person1` exists only in the scope of your if-block. When do you think you will get to the second else?

Answer (score 3):

1. The variable `person1` is declared inside the `if-else` statements and is not accessible outside of the scope of the respective `if-else` blocks. Therefore, the `person1` variable cannot be accessed outside of those blocks to call the IntroduceMyself method.
2. The `IntroduceMyself` function is defined as static which means you can call it using the class name followed by the function name, without the need for an instance of the class (`Human.IntroduceMyself(fullName, eyeColor, age)`). I would recommend to remove the static.

Here's the updated code

```cs
// Human class
internal class Human
{
    public string fullName;
    public string eyeColour;
    public int age;

    
    public Human(string fullName)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public Human(string fullName, string eyeColour)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.eyeColour = eyeColour;
    }
    public Human(string fullName, string eyeColour, int age)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.eyeColour = eyeColour;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // Function no longer static. Also removed the parameters since they are apart of the object
    public void IntroduceMyself()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, you have {1} eyes and you are {2} years old", fullName, eyeColour, age);
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
class Program
{
    static string fullName;
    static string eyeColour;
    static int age;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetDetails();
        // defining the person 
        Human person1 = null;
        if (eyeColour == "")
        { 
             person1 = new Human(fullName); 
        }
        else if (eyeColour != "")
        { 
             person1 = new Human(fullName, eyeColour); 
        }
        else
        { 
             person1 = new Human(fullName, eyeColour, age); 
        }

        person1.IntroduceMyself();
    }

    public static void GetDetails()
    {    
        Console.Write("Hello! To start, please enter your full name:");
        fullName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Would you like to input your eye colour? y / n :");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your eye colour:");
            eyeColour = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.Write("Would you like to input your age? y / n :");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your age:");
            while(!(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)))
            {
                Console.Write("There was an error! Please try again:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that, if eyeColour is null:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFn5x.png